# Заменить несколько строк текста

Tags: php

У нас есть несколько строк текста:

```
чтобы сделать перевод строки, просто добавьте два пробела в конец строки
чтобы добавить код программы, предварите его четырьмя пробелами
основные HTML тэги также поддерживаются
```

Нам отсюда надо заменить две первые строки. Как это сделать?

Т.е. чтобы получилось так:

```
замена
основные HTML тэги также поддерживаются
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
 var afterText = string.split("\n").splice(2);
 result = preText + "\n" + afterText.join("\n");
 // где preText - строка заменяющая первые 2
 // string - базовая строка
```

PHP:

```
 $lines = explode("\n", $string);
 $afterTextArray = array_splice( $lines, 2 );
 $result = $preText . "\n" . implode( $afterTextArray );
 // где $preText - текст замены
 // $string - базовая строка
```

---

PS: каков вопрос таков и ответ =\

Comment: Если писать подробно, то никто не отвечает. Поэтому кратко и написал. Вот вопрос более подробный: http://hashcode.ru/questions/81157/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: Я к тому что вопрос - **элементарный** и правильно делают что не отвечают. Что вы хотите? Готового кода?

Алгоритм описан, все что вам нужно это написать свою функцию. Если есть какие-то более **конкретные** вопросы - задавайте, с радостью помогу, если нет - учите мат.часть и приходите после.

Comment: Вообще на ваш вопрос ответ я дал, а то что на ваш предыдущий не отвечают "как-бы" намекает на то, что вопрос из разряда "сделай за меня, а я плюсиг поставлю !11!АДЗИН!1!"

Comment: В чем проблема? Сколько надо заплатить за Ваш ответ?